# jQuery Tools / Fancybox Conflict. "uncaught exception: Could not find Overlay: example_group"

Tags: fancybox, jquery-tools

I have jQueryTools installed and running smoothly throughout my site, except for one place, where I fear a conflict with FancyBox is preventing the Overlay form launching.  I am using Fancybox on that page to present a group of pictures.  Fancybox identifies the pictures to present by using rel="example_group".

I use jquery Tools Overlay to launch some form overlays using  rel="#overlay".

The weird thing is that the Fancybox pictures prevent just fine, but the jquery Tools Overlay just follows the SRC instead of launching into the overlay.  This makes me think that the the "uncaught exception: Could not find Overlay: example_group" message I am seeing in Firebug is coming from jquery Tools and preventing from working properly.

Any ideas what I can do to make them play along nicely?

Thanks.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, you were using `rel="#overlay"` and `rel="example_group"`, you will get the error with `example_group` because it doesn't have a hash (# - aka octothorpe) character in front of it.

I had the same problem and your question helped me find the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Tools lets you change the trigger for overlays, but it always uses the `rel` attribute to find the name of the overlay.

You are getting that error because if you are using `overlay()`, any element on the page with the `rel` attribute that matches your trigger selector will be assumed to be a trigger and jquery tools will look for an overlay div that matches the value of that `rel` attribute. If none is found, it will throw that error.

What you could do, is use a more precise selector to trigger the jQuery Tools overlay like:

```
$('a.jQueryToolsOverlay').overlay();
```

That way it will only look at the `rel` attribute of a tags that have the class `jQueryToolsOverlay`